# simple html dom parser can't get correct value

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I scrape using [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$html = getSslPage('http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4-sprint');

$result = $html->find('.forumbox-header',0); //error here

echo $result;
```

I execpt the output will be Sprint Samsung Galaxy Note 4 which has class of forumbox-header. I have no idea I got an error saying `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object` there.

Comment: $result is a string as it's getting the return value from the URL you've requested. It's not an object.

Comment: Also, given the code provided, it doesn't look like you actually use simple html dom at all. P.s. perhaps using the built in [DOM functionality](http://php.net/dom) might be worth a look too.

Comment: @JonStirling are you sure? When I do echo $html; I loaded the requested page, not string.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. Try `var_dump($html);`, add the output to your question.

Comment: `$result = curl_exec($ch);` which returns string (the html page).
Since you get a string, you can use the `str_get_html` function of that library. `$result = str_get_html($html);`

Comment: @JonStirling yes it's string. Thanks!

Comment: Since it helped, I'm about to offer it as an answer. Please approve it if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getSslPage` function returns a `string` (the html source code of the $url page).

While the returned value is a string, you're treating it as an object `$html->find` and therefore the error you get.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

The Simple Html DOM Parser library has 2 functions to create a DOM object:

- `file_get_html` - Create a DOM object from URL
- `str_get_html` - Create a DOM object from string

Since you already have the HTML string, just edit your code as the following:

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
$result = $html->find('.forumbox-header',0);
```